# How to know which exception is thrown from errorhandler in dead letter queue listener?

Tags: spring, rabbitmq, spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

I have a quorum queue (myQueue) and it's dead letter queue (myDLQueue). We have several exceptions which we separated as Retryable or Fatal. But sometimes in below listener we make an api call that throws RateLimitException. In this case the application should increase both of retry count and retry delay.

```
    @RabbitListener(queues = "#{myQueue.getName()}", errorHandler = "myErrorHandler")
    @SendTo("#{myStatusQueue.getName()}")
    public Status process(@Payload MyMessage message, @Headers MessageHeaders headers) {    
        int retries = headerProcessor.getRetries(headers);
        if (retries > properties.getMyQueueMaxRetries()) {
            throw new RetriesExceededException(retries);
        }
        if (retries > 0) {
            logger.info("Message {} has been retried {} times. Process it again anyway", kv("task_id", message.getTaskId()), retries);
        }

        // here we send a request to an api. but sometimes api returns rate limit error in case we send too many requests.
        // In that case makeApiCall throws RateLimitException which extends RetryableException

        makeApiCall() // --> it will throw RateLimitException
        
        if(/* a condition that needs to retry sending the message*/) {
            throw new RetryableException()
        }

        if(/* a condition that should not retry*/){
            throw new FatalException()
        }

        return new Status("Step 1 Success!");
    }
```

I have also an error handler (myErrorHandler) that catches thrown exceptions from above rabbit listener and manages retry process according to the type of the exception.

```
  public class MyErrorHandler implements RabbitListenerErrorHandler {

    @Override
    public Object handleError(Message amqpMessage,
            org.springframework.messaging.Message<?> message,
            ListenerExecutionFailedException exception) {

        // Check if error is fatal or retryable
        if (exception.getCause() /* ..is fatal? */) {
            return new Status("FAIL!");
        }

        // Retryable exception, rethrow it and let message to be NACKed and retried via DLQ 
        throw exception;
    }
  }
```

Last part I have is a DLQHandler that listens dead letter queue messages and send them to original queue (myQueue).

```
    @Service
public class MyDLQueueHandler {

    private final MyAppProperties properties;
    private final MessageHeaderProcessor headerProcessor;
    private final RabbitProducerService rabbitProducerService;

    public MyDLQueueHandler(MyProperties properties, MessageHeaderProcessor headerProcessor, RabbitProducerService rabbitProducerService) {
        this.properties = properties;
        this.headerProcessor = headerProcessor;
        this.rabbitProducerService = rabbitProducerService;
    }

    /**
     * Since message TTL is not available with quorum queues manually listen DL Queue and re-send the message with delay.
     * This allows messages to be processed again.
     */
    @RabbitListener(queues = {"#{myDLQueue.getName()}"}"})
    public void handleError(@Payload Object message, @Headers MessageHeaders headers) {
        String routingKey = headerProcessor.getRoutingKey(headers);
        Map<String, Object> newHeaders = Map.of(
                MessageHeaderProcessor.DELAY, properties.getRetryDelay(), // I need to send increased delay in case of RateLimitException.
                MessageHeaderProcessor.RETRIES_HEADER, headerProcessor.getRetries(headers) + 1
        );
        rabbitProducerService.sendMessageDelayed(message, routingKey, newHeaders);
    }
}
```

In the above handleError method inputs there is not any information related to exception instance thrown from MyErrorHandler or MyQueue listener. Currently I have to pass retry delay by reading it from app.properties. But I need to increase this delay if RateLimitException is thrown. So my question is how do I know which error is thrown from MyErrorHandler while in the MyDLQueueHandler?

Answer (score 0):

When you use the normal dead letter mechanism in RabbitMQ, there is no exception information provided - the message is the original rejected message. However, Spring AMQP provides a `RepublishMessageRecoverer` which can be used in conjunction with a retry interceptor. In that case, exception information is published in headers.

See https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/docs/current/reference/html/#async-listeners

> The RepublishMessageRecoverer publishes the message with additional information in message headers, such as the exception message, stack trace, original exchange, and routing key. Additional headers can be added by creating a subclass and overriding additionalHeaders().

```java
@Bean
RetryOperationsInterceptor interceptor() {
    return RetryInterceptorBuilder.stateless()
            .maxAttempts(5)
            .recoverer(new RepublishMessageRecoverer(amqpTemplate(), "something", "somethingelse"))
            .build();
}
```

The interceptor is added to the container's advice chain.

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-amqp/blob/57596c6a26be2697273cd97912049b92e81d3f1a/spring-rabbit/src/main/java/org/springframework/amqp/rabbit/retry/RepublishMessageRecoverer.java#L55-L61

```
    public static final String X_EXCEPTION_STACKTRACE = "x-exception-stacktrace";

    public static final String X_EXCEPTION_MESSAGE = "x-exception-message";

    public static final String X_ORIGINAL_EXCHANGE = "x-original-exchange";

    public static final String X_ORIGINAL_ROUTING_KEY = "x-original-routingKey";
```

The exception type can be found in the stack trace header.

Comment: They're Kafka headers and I asked for Rabbitmq.

Comment: Sorry - updated for RabbitMQ.

Comment: Your solution is spring's own retry mechanism. But I use my own errorhandler and want to manage the retry mechanism myself. Your solution could be the solution if the recoverer worked after the errorhandler. So I just want to see in MyDLQueueHandler what the exception I throw from MyErrorHandler is.

Comment: Instead of throwing an exception from the listener error handler, you need to publish the message to the DLQ yourself, adding a header to indicate which exception was thrown. As I said, when RabbitMQ routes to the DLQ, the message is the original - there is no AMQP protocol to tell the broker what happened. You can use similar code to the that in the framework's recoverer.